# Strange color code? Convert to Hex?

Tags: c#, html, css

I am currently making a web based simplified tool of our ERP we are using.
From our ERP we can assign colors to the status of an order. I made a new table in the database to store this color code. In the code I check for the statusID and the color. Then I am trying to add this colorcode as a background-color. However, the colorcodes I get from the ERP are not Hex-codes? Maybe anyone can tell me how and if it is possible to convert those codes into hex?

Here I select the color: [image]

And when I add a breakpoint for the colorcode: 
[image]

edit: Also, could someone tell me what kind of color code this is? would make it easier to google. The color code from the print screen is "16777088"

Comment: It's in decimal. Try to convert to hex using: `string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this fix on the web:

```
 int x = int.Parse(ProdBOOStatusBarColor);
            string colorHex = x.ToString("X6");
            StringBuilder color = new StringBuilder();
            color.Append("#");
            color.Append(colorHex.Substring(4, 2));
            color.Append(colorHex.Substring(2, 2));
            color.Append(colorHex.Substring(0, 2));
            color.ToString();
```

This seems to work for some reason, maybe someone here can explain what those substrings are doing there?

Comment: I'm just guessing but my thought is that when you specify the color as hex it has to specified as red, green, blue so the substring is just re-arranging the colors in the correct order. Like I said, just a guess I have done no research on that.

Answer (score 1):

You may wan't to try it with `System.Drawing.Color` which contains the methods `FromArgb` and `ToHex`.

So your solution could look like this

```
var hex = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(ProdBOOStatusBarColor)).ToHex();
```

Another way would be to parse use string functions `ToString` and [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) (or other string concatenation functions like `string.Format`, `string.Concat`, ...).
Example:

```
var hex2 = $"#{int.Parse(ProdBOOStatusBarColor):X}";
```

Answer (score 0):

16777088 is a decimal color so you need to convert to HEX (in your case is FFFF80). This color is a light yellow. 
You can use [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) page to check the colors.

Comment: I've converted it and I get a light yellow color indeed. however, I have selected the blue color from the print screen?

Comment: Post the code where you are getting the color from the print screen. Maybe your have a mistake parsing the values or similar.

Comment: It' not a code. It's the color picker from the print screen.

Comment: It should have a function that obtain the color from the view, if not, how do you get 1677708?

Comment: the ERP stores it into the database. Only thing I do is retrieve data from database

Comment: Mmm try Color c = Color.FromArgb(Integer.valueOf(your String)); If works, you can use c.R (to get red), etc.